# How to filter out games with evaluation from large PGN file?

Tags: computer-chess, evaluation

I have a huge 100M games in one PGN file - some % of it is stockfish evaluated, I want to use pgn-extract to extract those evaluated only, Is there a way of doing so?

examples of games with and without evaluation:

[game with no evaluation](https://gist.github.com/int8/aa7fdbda7c449d018237d16e0a80f6b8)

[game with evaluation](https://gist.github.com/int8/6b723c72af00b9bc7802d014020535fd)

Comment: Have you read the [pgn-extract](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/pgn-extract/help.html) documentation?

Comment: I have. I tried `-trules` where `rules` is a file with regex `*eval*` - this did not help

Comment: Could you post 1 game with annotation and 1 game without annotation?

Comment: sure, 

[game with no evaluation](https://gist.github.com/int8/aa7fdbda7c449d018237d16e0a80f6b8)

 [game with evaluation](https://gist.github.com/int8/6b723c72af00b9bc7802d014020535fd)

Comment: now by looking at PGN specs It seems I really want to search "by comments"

Comment: ended up going for cumbersome (but so far working) `awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\[Event" } ; { RS = "\[Event" } ; /%eval/ { print "[Event" $0  }' input.pgn`

Comment: pgn-extract doesn't have an option for that but you could use it as part of a pipeline to achieve what you want:
`pgn-extract -w10000 input.pgn | grep '%eval' | pgn-extract --output output.pgn`
That way, you could add further selection criteria to the first pass if required.